# Definition::addMethodCall Is not calling the set method

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3, symfony3.x

I am trying to upgrade Symfony from 2.3 to 3.4. At the moment I am try to fix an issue with the dependancy injection. It seems like the old version of the `DependencyInjection\Definition` class would call the Factory method when the factory was set, but this has changed?

I have tried to using this guides to upgrade the code:
https://gist.github.com/mickaelandrieu/5211d0047e7a6fbff925#dependencyinjection. But, I believe that the behaviour of the class has changed.

So this is the original code:

```
public function getSymfonyValue()
{
    $def = new \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition("Zend_Config");
    $def->setFactoryClass(__CLASS__);
    $def->setFactoryMethod('valueFactory');
    $def->addArgument($this->_configPath);
    return $def;
}
```

which invokes this method:

```
public function valueFactory($configPath){
    ...
    return $value;
}
```

I have updated the body of the method to this:

```
$def = new \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition("Zend_Config");
$def->setFactory(__CLASS__);
$def->addMethodCall('valueFactory', [$this->_configPath]);
return $def;
```

I expected the code to call the function `valueFactory`, but this function is never called. This could be because the old code does not have a container? I am not sure

Answer (score 0):

The `setFactory` method expect a callable, not just a class.
The `addMethodCall` will call a function on the service itself, not his factory.

What you want to do is :

```
$def->setFactory(array(__CLASS__, 'valueFactory'))
$def->setArguments(array($this->_configPath))
```

It means, you will create the service by calling the factory method, with the given arguments.

Comment: So i have changed the method to `$def->addArgument($this->_configPath);` as `setArguments ` does not exist, but i am still having the same problem

Comment: I have managed to use `$def->setArguments([$this->_configPath]);`, but I have the same issue

Comment: How is defined your factory? Is it a service?